Enabling "detectUnsafeIntentLaunch" in strictMode throws warning even for Implicit Intent with setPackage
I have enabled detectUnsafeIntentLaunch in strict mode to test for change while targeting for android SDK 35 in my SDK.
I have the following code where I send a broadcast and it is caught within the application .
code to send broadcast
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("my_custom_action").putExtras(extras)
    .setPackage(context.getPackageName()));

code to register and receive the broadcast
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("my_custom_action");
internalReceiver = new OpenedNotificationReceiver();

ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, internalReceiver, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

google recommends to mark setPackage on Implict Intents yet still throws warnings -> https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10399926?hl=en
I have set the package as recommended; I am getting warning. Does anyone know how can I get rid of these warning or are they false positive?

StrictMode policy violation:
android.os.strictmode.UnsafeIntentLaunchViolation: Launch of unsafe
intent:

as the package is set to my own this should not throw any warning, i dont know which activity which will handle this as it part of the app but not my SDK code and I cannot add it as component and make it explicit as it might keep changing.
